# SBT - compilation on remote machine

Tags: sbt

I am thinking about following feature:

1. Run `sbt compile`.
2. Your local instance of SBT connects to remote instance of SBT which does the hard work.
3. Run `sbt compile` on another machine on the same version of the code (for now, I am not specifiyng what *version* means).
4. Your local instance of SBT connects to remote instance of SBT which immediately returns cached result of compilation.

Did anyone try implementing that? How hard would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already work being done on this by the sbt team. I'm not quite sure which version it is scheduled for, so I won't say. For a start, you can see the [sbt Wiki - Client server split](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/wiki/Client-server-split). From that page:

> **Client server split**
>
> This is a discussion document about a client-server setup where a
>   per-project sbt daemon would be shared among editors, IDEs, and any
>   other clients a developer may be using.
>
> Some issues will have to be figured out through prototyping, but we
>   are doing our best to frame the overall problem and anticipate
>   solutions.
>
> **The concept**
>
> Each project-to-be-built should have a “build model,” implemented as a
>   per-project server process, where "view-controllers" (aka clients) may
>   be apps such as:
>
> - IDEs (Eclipse, ENSIME, Idea, etc.)
> - Command line tools
> - Standalone tools such as Activator, profilers, etc.
> - The limited on-reload in-browser UI offered by Play
> - Notification tools (using growl, gnome-shell, stuff like that)

You can also see the following discussion on the sbt-dev google group: [client-server split for sbt.next](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sbt-dev/1TvYrLF4ExU).